# how can i solve this error while running application in blackberry simulator?

Tags: blackberry

hi i am getting this error in console while running application and it is not build my app package.Following is my error.

```
C:\Eclipse\plugins\net.rim.ejde.componentpack5.0.0_5.0.0.25\components\bin\rapc.exe
-convertpng -quiet codename=deliverables\Standard\5.0.0\Weed deliverables\Standard\5.0.0\Weed.rapc
-sourceroot=D:\Hasmukh\Blackberry\BlackBerryWorkspace\Weed\src;D:\Hasmukh\Blackberry\BlackBerryWorkspace\Weed\res
-import=C:\Eclipse\plugins\net.rim.ejde.componentpack5.0.0_5.0.0.25\components\lib\net_rim_api.jar D:\Hasmukh\Blackberry\BlackBerryWorkspace\Weed\bin D:\Hasmukh\Blackberry\BlackBerryWorkspace\Weed\src\com\weedclass\CommonFunction.java:102: Warning!: method 'com.weedclass.CommonFunction.ReadFile()' not invoked. I/O Error: Cannot run program "jar": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified Packaging project Weed failed (took 4.162 seconds)
```

Thanx in advance.

Comment: i think you need to set jarfile path. see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7291442/error-cannot-run-program-jar-createprocess-error-2-the-system-cannot-find-t

Answer (score 0):

The solution can be found here: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/I-O-Error-CreateProcess/ta-p/445949