# Fail to run Blackberry Advanced UI example

Tags: java, eclipse, blackberry, user-interface

I am a beginner for blackberry development (java). I have experience of C/C++, Qt/QML but no Java skill. I have successfully played with other examples on simulator and device.
However, I downloaded the code from Github and import to Blackberry Eclipse Plug-in (Version 1.5.0) with JDK 6.0 and 7.0. It fails to run on simulator or device and errors:

```
Packaging project Advanced UI

C:\Eclipse\plugins\net.rim.ejde.componentpack6.0.0_6.0.0.43\components\bin\rapc.exe -quiet codename=deliverables\Standard\6.0.0\Advanced_UI -sourceroot=C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\workspace\Advanced UI\src -import=C:\Eclipse\plugins\net.rim.ejde.componentpack6.0.0_6.0.0.43\components\lib\net_rim_api.jar deliverables\Standard\6.0.0\Advanced_UI.rapc C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\workspace\Advanced UI\bin

C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\workspace\Advanced UI\src\com\samples\toolkit\ui\FieldDimensionUtilities.java:49: Warning!: method 'com.samples.toolkit.ui.FieldDimensionUtilities.getBorderHeight(Field)' not invoked.

C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\workspace\Advanced UI\src\com\samples\toolkit\ui\FieldDimensionUtilities.java:64: Warning!: method 'com.samples.toolkit.ui.FieldDimensionUtilities.getBorderAndPaddingWidth(Field)' not invoked.

C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\workspace\Advanced UI\src\com\samples\toolkit\ui\FieldDimensionUtilities.java:79: Warning!: method 'com.samples.toolkit.ui.FieldDimensionUtilities.getBorderAndPaddingHeight(Field)' not invoked.

C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\workspace\Advanced UI\src\com\samples\toolkit\ui\component\BitmapButtonField.java:52: Warning!: method 'com.samples.toolkit.ui.component.BitmapButtonField.setImage(Bitmap)' not invoked.

C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\workspace\Advanced UI\src\com\samples\toolkit\ui\component\BitmapButtonField.java:57: Warning!: method 'com.samples.toolkit.ui.component.BitmapButtonField.setFocusImage(Bitmap)' not invoked.

C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\workspace\Advanced UI\src\com\samples\toolkit\ui\component\BitmapGaugeField.java:145: Warning!: method 'com.samples.toolkit.ui.component.BitmapGaugeField.getNumValues()' not invoked.

C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\workspace\Advanced UI\src\com\samples\toolkit\ui\component\BitmapSliderField.java:222: Warning!: method 'com.samples.toolkit.ui.component.BitmapSliderField.getNumStates()' not invoked.

C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\workspace\Advanced UI\src\com\samples\toolkit\ui\component\BitmapSliderField.java:229: Warning!: method 'com.samples.toolkit.ui.component.BitmapSliderField.getColour()' not invoked.

C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\workspace\Advanced UI\src\com\samples\toolkit\ui\component\EmbossedButtonField.java:96: Warning!: method 'com.samples.toolkit.ui.component.EmbossedButtonField.setText(String)' not invoked.

C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\workspace\Advanced UI\src\com\samples\toolkit\ui\component\HyperlinkButtonField.java:1: Warning!: member data 'int _menuOrdinal' not required in class: com.samples.toolkit.ui.component.HyperlinkButtonField

C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\workspace\Advanced UI\src\com\samples\toolkit\ui\component\HyperlinkButtonField.java:1: Warning!: member data 'int _menuPriority' not required in class: com.samples.toolkit.ui.component.HyperlinkButtonField

C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\workspace\Advanced UI\src\com\samples\toolkit\ui\component\HyperlinkButtonField.java:144: Warning!: method 'com.samples.toolkit.ui.component.HyperlinkButtonField.getMenuText()' not invoked.

C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\workspace\Advanced UI\src\com\samples\toolkit\ui\component\HyperlinkButtonField.java:153: Warning!: method 'com.samples.toolkit.ui.component.HyperlinkButtonField.getMenuItem()' not invoked.

C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\workspace\Advanced UI\src\com\samples\toolkit\ui\component\LabeledSwitch.java:43: Warning!: member data 'boolean _selected' not required in class: com.samples.toolkit.ui.component.LabeledSwitch

C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\workspace\Advanced UI\src\com\samples\toolkit\ui\component\LabeledSwitch.java:88: Warning!: method 'com.samples.toolkit.ui.component.LabeledSwitch.setOn(boolean)' not invoked.

C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\workspace\Advanced UI\src\com\samples\toolkit\ui\component\LabeledSwitch.java:93: Warning!: method 'com.samples.toolkit.ui.component.LabeledSwitch.getOnState()' not invoked.

C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\workspace\Advanced UI\src\com\samples\toolkit\ui\component\ListStyleButtonField.java:139: Warning!: method 'com.samples.toolkit.ui.component.ListStyleButtonField.setText(String)' not invoked.

C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\workspace\Advanced UI\src\com\samples\toolkit\ui\component\RatingField.java:59: Warning!: member data 'int _rop' not required in class: com.samples.toolkit.ui.component.RatingField

C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\workspace\Advanced UI\src\com\samples\toolkit\ui\component\RatingField.java:109: Warning!: method 'com.samples.toolkit.ui.component.RatingField.getNumValues()' not invoked.

C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\workspace\Advanced UI\src\com\samples\toolkit\ui\component\SliderField.java:75: Warning!: member data 'int _progressWidth' not required in class: com.samples.toolkit.ui.component.SliderField

C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\workspace\Advanced UI\src\com\samples\toolkit\ui\component\SliderField.java:218: Warning!: method 'com.samples.toolkit.ui.component.SliderField.getValue()' not invoked.

C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\workspace\Advanced UI\src\com\samples\toolkit\ui\component\SliderField.java:223: Warning!: method 'com.samples.toolkit.ui.component.SliderField.getNumValues()' not invoked.

C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\workspace\Advanced UI\src\com\samples\toolkit\ui\component\SwitchField.java:54: Warning!: method 'com.samples.toolkit.ui.component.SwitchField.setOn(boolean)' not invoked.

C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\workspace\Advanced UI\src\com\samples\toolkit\ui\component\SwitchField.java:59: Warning!: method 'com.samples.toolkit.ui.component.SwitchField.getOnState()' not invoked.

C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\workspace\Advanced UI\src\com\samples\toolkit\ui\container\JustifiedHorizontalFieldManager.java:58: Warning!: method 'com.samples.toolkit.ui.container.JustifiedHorizontalFieldManager.addLeftField(Field)' not invoked.

C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\workspace\Advanced UI\src\com\samples\toolkit\ui\container\JustifiedHorizontalFieldManager.java:67: Warning!: method 'com.samples.toolkit.ui.container.JustifiedHorizontalFieldManager.addRightField(Field)' not invoked.

C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\workspace\Advanced UI\src\com\samples\toolkit\ui\container\JustifiedHorizontalFieldManager.java:139: Warning!: method 'com.samples.toolkit.ui.container.JustifiedHorizontalFieldManager.getLeftField()' not invoked.

C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\workspace\Advanced UI\src\com\samples\toolkit\ui\container\JustifiedHorizontalFieldManager.java:144: Warning!: method 'com.samples.toolkit.ui.container.JustifiedHorizontalFieldManager.getRightField()' not invoked.

C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\workspace\Advanced UI\src\com\samples\toolkit\ui\container\JustifiedVerticalFieldManager.java:102: Warning!: method 'com.samples.toolkit.ui.container.JustifiedVerticalFieldManager.getTopField()' not invoked.

C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\workspace\Advanced UI\src\com\samples\toolkit\ui\container\JustifiedVerticalFieldManager.java:107: Warning!: method 'com.samples.toolkit.ui.container.JustifiedVerticalFieldManager.getBottomField()' not invoked.

C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\workspace\Advanced UI\src\com\samples\toolkit\ui\container\TwoColumnField.java:66: Warning!: method 'com.samples.toolkit.ui.container.TwoColumnField.getLeftField()' not invoked.

C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\workspace\Advanced UI\src\com\samples\toolkit\ui\container\TwoColumnField.java:71: Warning!: method 'com.samples.toolkit.ui.container.TwoColumnField.getRightField()' not invoked.

C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\workspace\Advanced UI\src\com\samples\toolkit\ui\decor\BitmapMask.java:94: Warning!: method 'com.samples.toolkit.ui.decor.BitmapMask.getTop()' not invoked.

C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\workspace\Advanced UI\src\com\samples\toolkit\ui\decor\BitmapMask.java:99: Warning!: method 'com.samples.toolkit.ui.decor.BitmapMask.getRight()' not invoked.

C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\workspace\Advanced UI\src\com\samples\toolkit\ui\decor\BitmapMask.java:104: Warning!: method 'com.samples.toolkit.ui.decor.BitmapMask.getBottom()' not invoked.

C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\workspace\Advanced UI\src\com\samples\toolkit\ui\decor\BitmapMask.java:109: Warning!: method 'com.samples.toolkit.ui.decor.BitmapMask.getLeft()' not invoked.

C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\workspace\Advanced UI\src\com\samples\toolkit\ui\decor\BitmapMask.java:114: Warning!: method 'com.samples.toolkit.ui.decor.BitmapMask.getWidth()' not invoked.

C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\workspace\Advanced UI\src\com\samples\toolkit\ui\decor\BitmapMask.java:119: Warning!: method 'com.samples.toolkit.ui.decor.BitmapMask.getHeight()' not invoked.

C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\workspace\Advanced UI\src\com\samples\toolkit\ui\component\RatingField.java:250: Warning!: local variable(s) { isConsumed } initialized but not used in: com.samples.toolkit.ui.component.RatingField.touchEvent(TouchEvent)

C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\workspace\Advanced UI\src\com\samples\toolkit\ui\container\HorizontalButtonFieldSet.java:51: Warning!: local variable(s) { availableWidth maxPreferredWidth } initialized but not used in: com.samples.toolkit.ui.container.HorizontalButtonFieldSet.sublayout(int,int)

C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\workspace\Advanced UI\src\com\samples\toolkit\ui\container\JustifiedEvenlySpacedHorizontalFieldManager.java:40: Warning!: local variable(s) { availableWidth maxPreferredWidth } initialized but not used in: com.samples.toolkit.ui.container.JustifiedEvenlySpacedHorizontalFieldManager.sublayout(int,int)

Error: Cannot run program "jar": CreateProcess error=2, ?????????

Packaging project Advanced UI failed (took 15.953 seconds)
```

How to solve this case? Thanks.

regards,
QC

Comment: My wild guess would be the ENV variable is not properly defined.
Also its a duplicate from [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7291442/error-cannot-run-program-jar-createprocess-error-2-the-system-cannot-find-t) follow one of the cheap tricks or properly set the ENV

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that you have set Java/bin folder to your PATH system environment variable.

Warnings are not the cause of the problem. The problem depicted on the line:

```
Error: Cannot run program "jar": CreateProcess error=2, ?????????
```

It means that BlackBerry compiler did not find standard java compiler (javac.exe) to continue the compilation process.

Make sure that the folder where javac.exe resides is accessible from anywhere via setting system PATH variable to JavaSDK/bin folder.

For instance if you have installed standard Java SDK to folder `C:\Java` then add the following string to your system PATH variable:

```
C:\Java\bin
```