# eclipse plugin unable to package project

Tags: blackberry, eclipse-plugin

After sometime, its happened unexpected error

`Error: Cannot run program "jar": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
Packaging project OrientalDailyBB failed (took 10.75 seconds)`

I tried below few ways,

1. reinstall plug in
2. reimport project
3. create new project and copy the class into it
4. copied jar file to jre7.0\bin
5. create new project without copy anything and it can run

I got no idea now. Its happened suddenly.

Comment: So, are you saying that you can you create a brand new, "Hello World" BlackBerry project, and build and run it successfully?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check following links:

- [Knowledge Base Article - I/O Error: CreateProcess](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/I-O-Error-CreateProcess/ta-p/445949)
- [Error: Cannot run program “jar”: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7291442/error-cannot-run-program-jar-createprocess-error-2-the-system-cannot-find-t)
- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1297067/431639) of the question A[pplication not getting deployed on Blackberry simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/788442/application-not-getting-deployed-on-blackberry-simulator)
- [I/O Error: Cannot run program "jar": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified Packaging project](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/I-O-Error-Cannot-run-program-quot-jar-quot-CreateProcess-error-2/td-p/1433897)
- [I/O Error: Cannot run program "jar": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/I-O-Error-Cannot-run-program-quot-jar-quot-CreateProcess-error-2/m-p/1164433/highlight/true#M162884)
- [Blackberry JDE: Eclipse I/O Error: Cannot run program "jar": CreateProcess error=2](http://rndm-snippets.blogspot.com/2011/10/blackberry-jde-eclipse-io-error-cannot.html)